# not able to access kubernetes service on localhost

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am not able to access kubernetes service on localhost:nodePort but can access the same on 127.0.0.1:nodePort.  Also i can access service from browser  like masterip:nodePort

below is output

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        4h26m
nginx        NodePort    10.109.106.21   <none>        80:30893/TCP   7m24s
[root@k8s-master ~]# curl -I 127.0.0.1:30893
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.17.5
Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2019 15:48:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 14:30:00 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5daf1268-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

[root@k8s-master ~]# curl -I localhost:30893
^C
[root@k8s-master ~]# ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.069/0.080/0.094/0.010 ms
```

Now i am worried that if localhost do not work.Is it that my network is not properly configured for k8 cluster
How to fix this issue.

Comment: To add to this, I am also having hte same issue but only from browsers installed ont eh machine. Curl works fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an old reported issue [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28988) that seems to be related to your problem.

According to that, it may be something to do with IPv6 and a solution is to add the `--ipv4` option to each execution of the `curl` command, or apply a permanent solution for the host by disabling IPv6 altogether.